# How to run React.js localhost application on chrome dev remote devices?

Tags: reactjs, chrome-debugging

I'm creating `React.js` application and running it on `localhost` port `5443`. I want to see my React.js app in mobile view. How can i run localhost in chrome remote devices.I'm able to connect remote devices on the chrome dev-tool but my `localhost` not running in remote device, throw error refused connection.

Answer (score 0):

this could be achieved with any browser if you follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device) question. The easiest way to achieve is to have both your PC and your mobile device connected to the same network then using the IP address that your router assigned to the PC copy that direction and use it on your mobile Browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, this solution i had already tried but not working .may be old solutions.